# Retrieve Azure Virtual network information using .net

Tags: .net, azure-virtual-network

i am new to Microsoft azure, i am trying to interact with azure using its .net sdk.
How can i retrieve the list of virtual networks and the corresponding subnets created in Azure, using .net?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Management Libraries, it is in a nuget package called: microsoft.windowsazure.management

Here is a sample:

```
var cred = new Microsoft.Azure.CertificateCloudCredentials("yoursubid", new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String("yourcert")));

using (var netclient = new NetworkManagementClient(cred))
{
  var networks = netclient.Networks.List();
  Console.WriteLine("Networks:");
  networks.VirtualNetworkSites.ToList().ForEach(x =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
    x.Subnets.ToList().ForEach(y => Console.WriteLine(y.Name));
  }
 );
```

}

If you need a more elaborate example look at [this blog post.](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2015/10/manage-azure-networks-using-the-net-azure-management-libraries/)